# saa7134 on Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, tv-tuner

I'm having a problem with my tv card Compro Videomate TV/PVR. I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 and I can't see the tv.

I've always had problems with this tv card altough trying I used to be able to make it work, but now I can't no more.

I've installed `tvtime` because I'm used to use that program.

I know that my card is number 40 (because it always worked with that number) and because I use tuner 41.
I live in argentina so I use PAL_Nc.

I've always ran the commands:

```
sudo modprobe -r saa7134_alsa
sudo modprobe -r saa7134
sudo modprobe saa7134 card=40 tuner=41
```

but now when I run them I get:

```
fmendezgnu@fmendezgnu-pc:~$ sudo modprobe -r saa7134_alsa [sudo]
password for fmendezgnu:  modprobe: ERROR:
../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:777 kmod_module_remove_module() could not
remove 'saa7134_alsa': Device or resource busy
fmendezgnu@fmendezgnu-pc:~$ sudo modprobe -r saa7134 modprobe: FATAL:
Module saa7134 is in use. fmendezgnu@fmendezgnu-pc:~$ sudo modprobe
saa7134 card=40 tuner=41
```